# QUEUE_CONNECTION 'database' works but 'redis' throws 'Array to String conversion'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

I am simply trying to run a Event & Listener cycle and pass a model into it

```
event(new LabelsCreated($model, 'string'));
```

This works perfectly with `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` however with `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`, it throws me an error:

> #message: "Array to string conversion"
>
> #code: 0
>
> #file: "/home/vagrant/Code/Upworks/myproj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/RedisQueue.php"
>
> #line: 302
>
> #severity: E_NOTICE

My Event class looks like this:

```
class LabelsCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    public $model;

    public $string;

    public function __construct($model, $string)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->string = $string;

        // comes here
    }
}
```

but it doesn't queue my Listener at all.

---

My config/queue.php, redis array looks like this:

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => ['default', 'export'],
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
 ],
```

May it be referring to key 'queue' value?

Comment: Where are you getting `$transaction` from?

Comment: Was a typo when trying to more generic in my question. It's just a model. Fixed the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem in my config/queue.php

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => ['default', 'export'], // THIS LINE
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
 ],
```

I tried keeping it as default

```
'queue' => 'default'
```

and it ran multiple queues on the same connection.

*Deeper Insight: [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multiple-queues-for-redis-connection?page=0#reply=461404](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multiple-queues-for-redis-connection?page=0#reply=461404_)*